# How to use startAfter on Firestore?

Tags: flutter

I want to update my gridview and get data from firestore with startAfter. 
My code how I get first data is below. 
How to use startAfter in next query?

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Posts').limit(6).getDocuments().then((snap){
      postList.clear();
      for(int i=0; i<snap.documents.length; i++){
        Post post = new Post(snap.documents[i]['imageUrl'],
            snap.documents[i]['userId'],
            snap.documents[i]['color'],
            snap.documents[i]['brand'],
            snap.documents[i]['sex'],
            snap.documents[i]['category']);
        postList.add(post);
      }
      setState(() {
        print('Length : $postList.Lenth');
      });
    });
```

Next query.

````
Firestore.instance.collection('Posts').startAfter(whats here?).limit(8).getDocuments().then((snap){
        for(int i=0; i<snap.documents.length; i++){
          Post post = new Post(snap.documents[i]['imageUrl'],
              snap.documents[i]['userId'],
              snap.documents[i]['color'],
              snap.documents[i]['brand'],
              snap.documents[i]['sex'],
              snap.documents[i]['category']);
          postList.add(post);
        }
        setState(() {
          print('Length : $postList.Lenth');
        });
      });```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anyone has such a problem then there is a solution

```
_lastDocument = snap.documents[snap.documents.length-1];

.orderBy('dataTime').startAfter([_lastDocument.data['dataTime']])
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass any value which one you have been received from firebase at last and it must be **unique**.

In your case you have to pass last element of postList's id argument.

EX:

**postList[postList.length - 1 ].id**

Comment: Okej but I do this like this. Add this to postList       ```snap.documents[i].documentID``` and ```startAfter(postList[postList.length-1].id)``` but I have error "Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'."  "Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'List<dynamic>'."

Comment: In below link video I found and it's working pretty well in my coda. Go and check out what you are missing https://youtu.be/coR4Y-DkrLc

Comment: Still error= "The argument type 'DocumentSnapshot' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'."

Answer (score 0):

As in the official video suggests https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&t=303s
at 4:20, is not good idea use "startAfter" because take as argument a List of values set by orderBy, (its kinda a mess, and error-prone as the video says, check the documentation for more info) instead use **startAfter Document**, in which you can put an entire DocumentSnapshot, ( the last document of your first call) with this you get cero chance to get unexpected results and is easier, here is the documentation [startAfterDocument method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfterDocument.html)

Comment: Do startAfter and startAfterDocument do exactly the same thing, only the parameters are different?